# Change data inside map operator for other observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm having small misunderstanding of working observables. Hope that somebody can help me.

The thing is I have two observables. I'm getting the value of first one and if it satisfy my condition, I want to change data inside other observable. And I don't want to combine them. When I try to change data - I call a function and it's not comming inside `map` of reactive chain in second observable. What I'm do wrong? (I guess all of it :D )

I've created a rude example of how is it looking. Here is a code and [link to playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzxkpv)

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.first$ = Observable.create(observer => observer.next(1));

  this.second$ = timer(0, 1000)
    .pipe(
      map(() => this.counter + this.incrementValue)
    )
    .subscribe(data => console.log('second', data));

  this.first$.pipe(
    map(value => {
      console.log('first a', value)
      return this.decrementValueInSecondObs()
    })
  ).subscribe(data => console.log(data))
}

private decrementValueInSecondObs() {
  this.second$
  .pipe(
    map(value => {
      console.log('SECOND VALUE', value)
      return this.counter - 2;
    })
  ).subscribe(a => console.log('first b', a))
}
```

And the **BONUS:** can anybody explain or attach the link to answer why I can work with `map` operator in rxjs when I'm only subscribed on his observable?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you want. Do you want to change `this.counter` that's used by your `second$` observable, when your `first$` observable emits? Like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7vhcid ?

Comment: Looking at the code examples and questions it seems like you misunderstand how the `subscribe` method works and what it does. Here is the video which helped me and a few other people https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LKMwkuK0ZE . It's t's related to RxJS 5 (there was no `pipe` back then), but the core concept hasn't 
 changed.